# Rename a property or give an alias name in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a situation where I generate a table from a SQL Server database as a model with Entity Framework, but it is related with another table in the database so inside the model is also a property with the second table name like this

```
public virtual ICollection<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I what to take data dynamically inside a controller in MVC which is called by Ajax. And as a result I have to expose the name of the second table in Ajax arguments. Is there any way to change the name of `Table2` using `MetadataType` attribute by creating another class `Table1Metadata` ?

Comment: If you mean change the relation dynamically i have to say you can't do that. but if you don't mean that please explain what you want more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fluent api to change a table name:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>().ToTable("MyCustomTable2Name");
}
```

This method can be overriden in your `DbContext`.